# Just a part of .attr() 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an img html block `<img src="folder1/folder2/folder3/logo1.png">` positioned inside a big div like this

```
<div id="editorial">
   <div id="img_editorial"><img src="folder1/folder2/folder3/logo1.png" /></div>
</div>
```

When user hovers the `<div id="editorial">` (mouseover) i want to read the attribute of `<img>` which is `folder1/folder2/folder3/logo1.png` extract the `logo1.png` from this and add `on_` to the logo ( `on_logo1.png` ) and then output it with `jquery .html() function` to overwritte `<div id="img_editorial">`

On mouseout i want to return to `logo1.png` ... because i have multiple background changes in that parent div ... so the basic functionality is to grayout a logo when mouse is over a big div (also div`s background changes ... etc) ...

So .. how can i read the `<img>` attribute and then extract logo1.png and not the whole `folder1/folder2/folder3/logo1.png` ...

Comment: Why couldn't you use css to do the mouse over effect?

Comment: because i have lots of logos with different sizes

Comment: You could do this with some JavaScript array push, pop, and join calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the attribute like this:

```
var img_src = $('#img_editorial img').attr('src');
```

This will give you:

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/logo1.png
```

Than you can split it with:

```
var split_img_src = img_src.split('/');
```

This will give you an array, something like:

```
split_img_src[0] = folder1;
split_img_src[1] = folder2;
split_img_src[2] = folder3;
split_img_src[3] = logo1.png;
```

so the last value in the array should always be the name of the file - no matter how long the directory tree is.

So you now have the file name, you can append what ever you want to it and do what ever you need.

Good luck.

Comment: is there a function to tell how long the array is ? (like `count` or something) ... `var abc = count(split_img_src[]) ... and then to split_img_src[abc] ` ???

Comment: `split_img_src[split_img_src.length - 1]` will give you the last element. Although a quick google search would have told you that :P

Comment: `split_img_src[split_img_src.lenght - 1]` isn't working ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Here! just a nice solution:

```
$('#img_editorial img').hover(function(){

   imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
   var imgSplit = imgSrc.split('/');
   var imgName = imgSplit[3];

   $(this).attr('src', imgSrc.replace(imgName, 'on_'+imgName) );

},function(){

    $(this).attr('src', imgSrc);

});
```

If you want, open Firebug and play with this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hwtdQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The following *should* do what you want. It just stores the original image using the jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) API and puts it back when on [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) of the `<div>`.

```
$('div#editorial').mouseenter(function() {
    var originalSrc = $('img', this).prop('src');
    $(this).data('originalSrc', originalSrc);
    var pathComponents = originalSrc.split('/');
    var logo = pathComponents.pop();
    pathComponents.push('on_' + logo);  
    $('img', this).prop('src', pathComponents.join('/'));
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('img', this).prop('src', $(this).data('originalSrc'));
});
```

[**The demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yUzmN/) *sort of* works but I have no `_on` image so it just 404s. I hope you get the idea :-)